# Using few ListView's in one activity and layout

Tags: android, listview, crash, android-activity, listactivity

I'm trying to organize data recieved by SMS messages in specified ListView's. 
I tried to create and activity which will contain 3 ListView's in one layout. 
But, while running the activity it crashes. 
Can someone help with this?

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/idList"
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="384dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/namesList"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="387dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/phonesList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="382dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the activity code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  public class DataLists extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
  ListView idList, namesList, phonesList;
  MyReciever mr;
  ArrayList<String>ids= new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String>names=new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String>phones=new ArrayList<String>();

  ArrayAdapter<String> idAdapter, namesAdapter, phonesAdapter;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_lists);
    idList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.idList);
    namesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.namesList);
    phonesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.phonesList);
    idAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ids );
    idList.setAdapter(idAdapter);
    namesAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    namesList.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
    phonesAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, phones);
    phonesList.setAdapter(phonesAdapter);

}
public void addItemToIdList(String st)
{
    ids.add(st);
    idAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItemToNamesList(String st)
{
    names.add(st);
    namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItemToPhonesList(String st)
{
    phones.add(st);
    phonesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[]msgs=null;
        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            Object[]pdus=(Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs=new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
            {
                int index=0, prev=0;
                String msgBody=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                 index=msgBody.indexOf(';');
                 prev=index;
                 String name=msgBody.substring(0, index);
                 addItemToNamesList(name);
                 msgBody=msgBody.substring(index+1);
                 index=msgBody.indexOf(';');
                 String id=msgBody.substring(prev, index);
                 addItemToIdList(id);
                 msgBody=msgBody.substring(index+1);
                 String phone=msgBody;
                 addItemToPhonesList(phone);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Put them in a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) ... a good example is the Google Play app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,But I wanted to show all 3 ListView's at one time. Eclipse does not show any errors, but while running it- it crahses. Where exactly did I mistake? How can I do what I told above?

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: 11-07 18:39:23.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.avissmsapplication/com.example.avissmsapplication.DataLists}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-07 18:39:23.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-07 18:39:23.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

Answer (score 0):

You have extended `ListActivity`. This is a convenience class that can be used to display a single `ListView`. The crash is clearly described in your logcat/stacktrace:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Since your layout contains 3 `ListView`s, you probably can't use `ListActivity` anyway. Just change your activity to extend `Activity` and go from there.